# Dynamic html content containing materializecss form not rendering angular directives

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-material, materialize, plunker

I have used materialize-css, AngularJS in my code. I have an issue in using angular directives(i.e., ng-model,ng-click etc) inside the form, which is created in between the table, on click of edit button.Please help me in finding the solution.

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nr9TfUGgOW3r8fNmlpsD?p=preview)!

```
Thank you.
```

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: ng-model not binding data in the form